# Technical difficulties with degenerate PDEs

Tags: black-scholes-pde

<sub>[Crossposted](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4494805) at Mathematics SE</sub>

---

I have seen lot of discussions in Math.stackexchange platform about 'degenerate partial differential equations'. But I still unclear about the 'technical difficulty' with the degeneracy present in the Black-Scholes model governing option pricing. While dealing the generalized Black-Scholes equation
$$\frac{\partial{V}}{\partial{t}}+\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2(S,t)S^2\frac{\partial^2{V}}{\partial{S}^2}+(r(S,t)-D(S,t))S \frac{\partial{V}}{\partial{S}}-r(S,t)V=0,~~~~S\in (0,\infty),~~~t\in(0,T),$$
with the terminal condition $V (S,T)=\max(S-E,0)$, most of the numerical analysts attempt transforming the price variable $S$ to a dimensionless variable $x=\ln S$, and claim thereby tackled the degeneracy of the model. I feel some trouble should be there near $S=0$ affecting the nature of the PDE. However, I got the exact definition from the [discussion](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1816237/).

In principle, I am interested to know about the analytical difficulty while dealing with such degenerate PDEs. I appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: Note that the Heston PDE is also degenerate